# How to use 'if' 'else' statements in hiveql?

Tags: hiveql

I am not sure if we can use if else in Hiveql or not. So wanted to know how we can write if else statements in hiveql

Comment: Have u considered using **Conditional Functions**  ?

https://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/conditional-functions-in-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF (Returns valueTrue when testCondition is true, returns valueFalseOrNull otherwise):

```
if(boolean testCondition, T valueTrue, T valueFalseOrNull)
```

Or CASE (When a = true, returns b; when c = true, returns d; else returns e):

```
CASE WHEN a THEN b WHEN c THEN d ELSE e END
```

Or any other supported [**conditional function**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF/#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions).